# Running totals from a fact table displayed by values from a linked date table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a mutation table on which I want to have a running total. This measure I can create succesfully as long as I present the data with the **date** of the mutation table.

However, the dates of the mutations are linked to a time_dimension table which contains, specifically relevant for this example, isoweek numbers.

When I try to present the data by these week numbers, the running total no longer works.

The data model:

[image]

I tried toggling filter directions in the data-model (which I shouldn't do), and working with the time_dim in the DAX code, but to no avail.

The code:

```
Balance = 
    VAR MaxDate = MAX ( AV_Mutations[Date])
    RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(AV_Mutations[Quantity]),
        AV_Mutations[Date] <= MaxDate,
        ALLSELECTED(AV_Mutations[Date])
    )
```

The data:

[image]

Table 1 shows that the code above goes wrong when applying week_numbers. It is in this format I want to present the data.

Table 2 shows that the code works when using **date** field from the Mutation table.

Table 3 shows the relation between mutation and date_dim works, but this should be obvious.

Can anyone help me or nudge me in the right direction calculating a running total over YearWeek_Number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're using the wrong date column in your measure.

Try something like this:

```
Balance = 
    VAR MaxDate = MAX ( AV_Mutations[Date])
    RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(AV_Mutations[Quantity]),
        Time_Dim[Full_Date] <= MaxDate,
        ALLSELECTED(Time_Dim[Full_Date])
    )
```